# Why service worker's message never gets to a client

Tags: javascript, service-worker, postmessage

I am trying to setup [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage#Browser_compatibility) and make it work however on the most simple one script file and one worker file it never sends a message to client from service worker. What can be the issue ?

### Browser:

**Google Chrome**
*Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

### main.js

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log(event.data.msg, event.data.url);
});

navigator.serviceWorker.register("sw.js")
  .then(function (registration) {
    console.log("ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ", registration.scope);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Service Worker Error", error);
  });
```

### sw.js

```
addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.waitUntil(async function() {
    // Exit early if we don't have access to the client.
    // Eg, if it's cross-origin.
    if (!event.clientId) return;

    // Get the client.
    const client = await clients.get(event.clientId);
    // Exit early if we don't get the client.
    // Eg, if it closed.
    if (!client) return;

    // Send a message to the client.
    client.postMessage({
      msg: "Hey I just got a fetch from you!",
      url: event.request.url
    });
  }());
});
```

I `console.log` in every place and the method `client.postMessage` is being called.

[image]
[image]

This works on
**Mozilla Firefox Quantum 58.0.2 (64-bit)**

Comment: Your service worker might not be controlling the page just yet - try claiming it and/or skipping waiting for it.

Comment: I did try, it didn't help though

Comment: @HenrikAndersson I updated sw code with it

Comment: Have you tried using `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage`?

Comment: but i want to send a message from service worker to a client not the other way around

Comment: do you mean a push notification?

Comment: @oninross no I mean `postMessage` - **The postMessage() method of Client allows a service worker to send a message to a client**

Answer (score 4):

You must get the client object first. Add this inside your `fetch` listener.

```
self.clients.matchAll().then(function (clients){
    clients.forEach(function(client){
        client.postMessage({
            msg: "Hey I just got a fetch from you!",
            url: event.request.url
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using this line to get a client by id `await clients.get(event.clientId);`

Comment: ok. i was finally able to pass a message from my service worker to my window using the above code. ...if you got yours working another way, good deal. The above works for me.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later today, after work and will post my results to let you know

Comment: this worked for me when the await clients.get didn't work